# GPS status in android studio - API level 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gps

I'm writing an android app with android studio in java targetting API 29 devices. I've written a GPSReceiver (which extends BroadcastReceiver) and I need to know if GPS status has changed (i.e. add a location listener).

In earlier versions of Android, I know this could be accomplished with

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
int state = Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
Log.i(TAG, "GPS status changed, new state = " + state);

if (state == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF)
  do_smth;
else
  do_smth_else;
```

And in Android 11 (API level 30) the next snippet seems to do it for me.

```
boolean state = intent.getIntExtra(LocationManager.EXTRA_LOCATION_ENABLED, -1);

if (state)
  do_smth;
else
  do_smth_else;
```

However, I don't know how get this exact behaviour in API 29.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code, it works for me

```
public boolean isGPSOn() {
    boolean check = false;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        check = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    return check;
}
```